# Scala: Objects have same class have different type?

Tags: scala, object, listbuffer

After defining a class in scala, the object that I create seems to be of different type.
Trying to create a ListBuffer of objects. Trying out in scala command line. Can someone explain this?

In the example bellow I create a `class z`. Object p and q seem to conflict when trying to add them to a `ListBuffer`

```
scala> class z()
defined class z

scala> var p = new z()
p: this.z = z@3755c76

scala> var q = new z()
q: this.z = z@63f8feb3

scala> var LB = ListBuffer[z](p,q)
<console>:19: error: type mismatch;
 found   : this.z
 required: this.z
       var LB = ListBuffer[z](p,q)
                              ^
<console>:19: error: type mismatch;    
 found   : this.z
 required: this.z
       var LB = ListBuffer[z](p,q)
                                ^
```

Comment: Were you trying this in the REPL? If you re-executed the first line (re-defining class z) after defining p and q, this could generate the sort of error you are seeing. In a clean run, I don't get a problem.

Comment: I am running this in spark shell. Does that make a difference. It running Scala2.9.3

Comment: I'm guessing it doesn't, but I couldn't say for sure. Try resetting and running the code again, being sure not to repeat any lines - presuming you can do a reset (in sbt's console, type `:reset`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an artifact of the current Spark Shell implementation (your example works fine in a regular Scala 2.9.3 shell); there's [a post on the spark-users](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/spark-users/error%243A%2420type%2420mismatch%7Csort%3arelevance/spark-users/bwAmbUgxWrA/HwP4Nv4adfEJ) mailing list that explains the problem in more detail and lists a few workarounds.